# Domain release from Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, release

I have just recently bought a domain from clickfunnels and apparently it wasn't released from Heroku site. Clickfunnels told me I should contact Heroku, but I contacted Heroku and got this message:
In order to verify ownership of this domain, we require that you set a DNS record on the apex/root domain (no sub-domain like 'www'). You'll want to make this change with your DNS provider.

I Contacted my DNS provider but they couldn't help me with that. What should I do? Just to let you know I don't understand much about releasing domain or all this programming stuff. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the domain name in question?

Comment: Hi Ron, crystalmarket.org

Answer (score 0):

The domain could be pointed to any service, in this case Heroku.

Since you are the owner of the domain name, you can change the NS servers of your domain name, They currently are:

```
Name Server: NS1.DNSIMPLE.COM
Name Server: NS2.DNSIMPLE.COM
Name Server: NS3.DNSIMPLE.COM
Name Server: NS4.DNSIMPLE.COM
```

You can use the NS provided by your hosting company, or free NS..

Once you have changed those NS you will be able to manage your domain's DNS and point it to anywhere YOU like.

You do not need to really do anything with Heroku, unless you want to use Heroku as a hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your answer, but still I don't really get why after buying domain from Clickfunnels they are telling me that it is necessary to release the domain. They said I need to contact my DNS provider because that website was owned by Heroku or something like that and thats what I am trying to do now but seriously I have no clue how to change NS or anything.

Comment: Ron, sorry but I didn't catch your email, could you please reach me valeriemisevi on gmail? Sorry for inconvenience